# Retrieve files from MongoDB using pymongo and gridfs for files larger than 16mb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

So I am trying to upload data larger than 16mb on a local database on an Azure Cosmos Emulator from a python app. The upload is perfect it creates the chunks along with the items. The problem I have though is on the download.

```
path = "eye1.zip"
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
with open(path, 'rb') as file1:
    grid = fs.put(file1)
    eye = fs.get(grid)
    print(eye.read())
```

The error I get all the time atthe .read() command is `pymongo.errors.ProtocolError: Message length (12753158) is larger than server max message size (4194304)`. So what is the correct procedure to download the data that I have just uploaded to my device? And why is this error appearing since gridfs suppose to let you stream more than 16mb of data ?

Comment: The PyMongo driver is only built and tested against the official MongoDB server. You mileage will vary against emulation environments like CosmosDB. I ran your code against MongoDB and it works. It fails on CosmosDB. I suggest you ask the folks at Microsoft for help.,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was partially solved by making an addition in the pymongo library in file network.py in line 198  with "max_message_size=50777216".

Answer (score 0):

Got non-interventionist solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673024/4355695 : Use `batch_size` parameter in [pymongo's .find()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert_one#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) function:

```
result = mdb['collection1'].find({}, batch_size=60)
```

My collection had v.large records. Using batch_size=1 seemed too low; 100 was causing the same error. After some trials I settled on this 60 number as optmimum. The speed of fetching data wasn't affected. I subsequently ran the same command over thousands of such records in multiple collections and didn't get any problem.